# Git почему ветка master всегда актуализируется с новой веткой

Tags: git, github

Ситуация следующая: у меня есть проект, ветка **master** актуальна с `origin master`. Я создал новую ветку:

```
git branch <some_feature_1>
git checkout <some_feature_1>
```

Внес изменения в проект из под ветки <**some_feature_1**>. Но когда я переключился обратно на master

```
git checkout master
```

чтобы сравнить со старыми изменениями (как было и как стало), то в master находится уже все тоже самое что я сделал в новой ветке. То есть как будто я не создавал новую ветку, а прост овсе изменения вносил в master.  Почему так происходит?

Comment: а коммит в новой ветке был?

Comment: Нет, не делал коммит

Comment: поэтому незакомиченные изменения видны в любой ветке. вернитесь в новую закомитьте изменения, а потом вернитесь в мастер и сравнивайте

Comment: *"все изменения вносил в master"* - "*не делал коммит*" - ¿вы же в курсе, что изменения хранятся в коммитах, а не в ветках? Ветки можно переставить в любой момент.

Comment: Да, моя вина и невнимательность. нужно делать коммиты в ветках, а затем переключать и смотреть изменения